# How to use value types in generics

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
public class Class1
{
    void ValueSpecific(string arg)
    {
        // do string stuff
    }
    void ValueSpecific(int arg)
    {
        // do int stuff
    }
    void ValueSpecific(float arg)
    {
        // do float stuff
    }
    void ValueGeneric(string arg)
    {
        // do stuff
        ValueSpecific(arg);
        // do more stuff
    }
    void ValueGeneric(int arg)
    {
        // do stuff
        ValueSpecific(arg);
        // do more stuff
    }
    void ValueGeneric(float arg)
    {
        // do stuff
        ValueSpecific(arg);
        // do more stuff
    }
    void Main(string s, int i, float f)
    {
        ValueGeneric(s);
        ValueGeneric(i);
        ValueGeneric(f);
    }
}
```

This works but the bodys of all three overloads of ValueGeneric are identical. I want to amalgamate them into one method, which would look something like:

```
void ValueGeneric<T>(T arg) where T: string, float, int
{
    // do stuff
    ValueSpecific(arg);
    // do more stuff
}
```

but this, of course, is not valid C#.
The best I can come up with is:

```
void ValueGeneric(object arg)
{
    // Do stuff
    if (arg is int)
    {
        ValueSpecific((int)arg);
    }
    else if (arg is string)
    {
        ValueSpecific((string)arg);
    }
    else if (arg is float)
    {
        ValueSpecific((float)arg);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Assert(false, "Invalid type)
    }
    // Do more stuff
}
```

but this seems very inelegant. I'd appreciate any suggestions. (While I would be interested in any solutions, one supported by .NET3.5 would be best, as that is what I am using.)

Comment: If you _really_ want to do this, you'd have to resort to using reflection.

Comment: what about an extension method ?

Comment: @JeffMercado is right. You have to use Reflection if you want it to be elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're doing the same stuff before and after in all of your overloads, you can apply the usual approach of factoring out what is different in the code and parameterize them.  The only things that change are the argument that is passed in and the action that you perform on that argument.  Pass them both in.

```
static void ValueGeneric<T>(T arg, Action<T> action)
{
    // do stuff
    action(arg);
    // do more stuff
}
```

Then call the generic method using the appropriate action (your `ValueSpecific` overloads will resolve itself nicely).

```
ValueGeneric(s, ValueSpecific);
ValueGeneric(i, ValueSpecific);
ValueGeneric(f, ValueSpecific);
```

Comment: I like that one. Thanks. BTW there were a whole bunch of other answers here a minute ago, including one from HatSoft that used 'dynamic' (which onoy works in .NET 4), but they've all disappeared. Luckily I grabbed HatSoft's solution. HatSoft, did you delete it, or is someone moderating the page?

Comment: @Dave. I deleted mine as it would not be a solution I would ever commit to. Others may have followed suit. The "dynamic" solution would worked but you are better having the specific methods to ensure you find problems at compile time instead of risking runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen of other, large .NET projects, you could include both the specific and generic overloads. If a  specific overload doesn't exist, they'll just use the generic version instead:

```
void ValueGeneric(int i);
void ValueGeneric(string s);
void ValueGeneric(float f);
void ValueGeneric<T>(T t);
```

By the structure of the code you posted, it seems like you want to do something to all the types before and after the contents of `ValueSpecific`, so you could make private `PreValueGeneric` and `PostValueGeneric` methods that all the `ValueGeneric` overloads call at the beginning and end to avoid code duplication between the overloads.

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider using an extension method for each type? It could be an alternative for this case.

you can define a class and define that methods. Like:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class Class1
    {
        static void ValueSpecific(this string arg)
        {
            // do string stuff
        }
        static void ValueSpecific(this int arg)
        {
            // do int stuff
        }  
    }
}
```

and then, when you want to use them, just do

```
Int32 myIntVar = 20;
myIntVar.ValueSpecific();
String myStringVar = "hi",
myStringVar.ValueSpecific();
```

you will have to add

```
using ExtensionMethods;
```

only declare the methods and use them.

Comment: An interesting idea, but unfortunately in the real world the ValueSpecific methods are not static, they are a non-static method of a class. It could be done with some hefty refactoring but I think it would end up being even more opaque.

Comment: yes, they are static, but I think it was interesting to post as an alternative.